# Привязать кнопку к месту на фоне резинового шаблона

Tags: html, css

Есть страничка сайта - большая фоновая картинка. Резиновая. На этой картинке в определенном месте (нарисованная дверь) нужно поставить кнопку(вход). Проблема в том, что когда шаблон расширяется, или сужается, кнопка не следует за ним, и оказывается на другом месте картинки (где угодно, но не на двери).
В дизайне плохо соображаю, помогите, как можно решить проблему.
На данный момент имеется цсс:

> ```
> *{
>   margin:0;
>   padding:0;
> }
> body{
>   background:#000;
>   font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
>   font-size:15px;
>   color: #fff;
>   text-transform:uppercase;
>   overflow-x:hidden;
> }
> .bg_img img{
>               width:100%;
>               position:fixed;
>               top:0px;
>               left:0px;
>               z-index:-1;
>           }
>               h2{
>               font-size:30px;
>               text-align:right;
>               position:absolute;
>               right:340px;
>               top:300px;
>               font-weight:normal;
>               /*text-shadow:  0 0 3px #0096ff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #0096ff, 0 0
> ```
>
> 70px #0096ff, 0 0 80px #0096ff, 0 0
> 100px #0096ff, 0 0 150px #0096ff;
>               */}

Comment: Кнопку вешаете абсолютно и указываете отступы в процентах.

Comment: а где стили для самой кнопки?

Comment: Можете показать страницу? Уверен, есть способ обойти проблему.

Comment: Вешаю абсолютно, указываю отступы в процентах - та же ерунда, что и в пикселях. Т.е. кнопка движется относительно окна браузера, а не относительно картинки. У меня тут параметры для кнопки выше указаны под стилем h2 =/ Кнопка - простая картинка со ссылкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попоробуйте прописать для кнопки, например

```
display:inline-block
```

или

```
display:block
```

добавьте к этому указание длины кнопки в пикселях, т.е. что-то типа

```
width:100px
```

Ну а дальше надо прописывать `float`, собственно поидее вот и все...

Comment: Спасибо!
display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20%;
                margin-top: 23%;
Вот эти условия практически держат кнопку на месте, хотя при уменьшении размеров фона она все-таки немного съезжает по горизонтали. Видимо, потому, что размер картинки-кнопки не изменяется.. есть ли возможность изменять размер кнопки вместе с размером фона? пробовала ставить width 100%, не сработало =(

Answer (score 0):

Нашла решение и для кнопки. В общем, если кому будет нужно сделать картинку с кнопкой, которая меняется под разрешение экрана вместе с фоном - используйте слои z-index. фон помещайте на -1 слой, картинку с кнопкой на 1 слой и т.п. Соответственно, настройки слоя для картинки:

> ```
> .stretch { width:100%;
>               display:inline;
>               float: right;
>                z-index: 1;}
> .stretch img { width: 25%; margin-top:24%; margin-left:58%;}
> ```

(топ и левый край задаете для своих кнопок соответственно тому, где они должны располагаться)
В этом случае она показывается там, где нужно, и уменьшается-увеличивается адекватно фону.